# ActiveJob issue implementing Delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job, rails-activejob

For my personal website build with Rails 5, I'm trying to implement a job for sending a contact form. I'm using the delayed_job_active_record gem.

I generated a job ContactMessageJob:

```
app/jobs/contact_message_job.rb

class ContactMessageJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :contact_message

  def perform(message)
    MessageMailer.send_message(message).deliver_now
  end
end
```

Then in the MessagesController I'm calling the perform_later method on ContactMessageJob:

```
app/controllers/messages_controller.rb

...
def create
  @message = Message.new(message_params)

  if @message.valid?
    ContactMessageJob.perform_later(@message)
    redirect_to contact_path, notice: "Your message has been sent."
  else
    flash[:alert] = "An error occured while delivering this message."
    render :new
  end
end
```

but when I'm trying to send a message through the contact form, I getting this error when executing ContactMessageJob.perform_later(@message):

```
ActiveJob::SerializationError at /contact
Unsupported argument type: Message
```

I'm a bit new to using ActiveJob, so I'm not sure how I can fix this. Any suggestions are very welcome.

my repo is at: https://github.com/acandael/personalsite/tree/job

greetings,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Rails' ActiveJob does serialization using [GlobalID](https://github.com/rails/globalid) and GlobalID know how to serialize primitive values (string, number) and ActiveRecord objects. Your Message class is an basic model which GID cannot serialize.

Probably easier option for you is to pass to the job the message_params directly and use them from the job itself

```
MessageMailer.send_message(message_params[:name], message_params[:email], message_params[:content]).deliver_later
```

*) You don't need the job class on contact_message_job.rb as you can send async email using the deliver_later method